# interact with FA2.0 Smart Contract

Tags: smart-contracts, fa2

I deployed a FA2.0 Smart Contract and would need to interact with it through Java. I tried to use Tezosj ([enter link description here](https://github.com/TezosRio/TezosJ_plainJava)) but it does not support FA2.0 smart contracts...hence, I would like to use directly RPC Calls to interact with nodes but I cannot see any documentation about it.
I also tried to look as tezos-client option but same thing I can only see details on FA1.2 Smart Contracts interaction.

I know that the usual way is to use Taquito for interaction but is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Octez nodes API doc is here https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/openapi.html

Marigold's nodes expose all endpoints:

- https://mainnet.tezos.marigold.dev/version
- https://ghostnet.tezos.marigold.dev/version
- https://kathmandunet.tezos.marigold.dev/version

Comment: great ! thanks, will look at it.

Comment: which end point can be used to interact with a FA2.0 Smart Contract ? I can see endpoints to view the endpoints but nothing related to exectution ? on the other hand, is it possible to call FA2.0 smart contract end points with tezos-client ?

Comment: Current API https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/docs/api/kathmandu-openapi.json

To request an onchain VIEW
`POST /helpers/scripts/run_script_view`

Comment: Calling an endpoint of a smartcontract is a transaction, you need to forge the relevant transation. It may be complex and there is SDK that help. I never try the JavaSDK but you have exemple here https://github.com/TezosRio/TezosJ_plainJava/blob/88b96d1a772aa326a842cd3361ea0d177e16619d/README.md?plain=1#L153